# Subgroup generated by subgroups $\langle A_1,B_1\rangle$ and $\langle A_2,B_2\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $A_1$, $A_2$, $B_1$, $B_2$ be subgroups of finite group $G$. It is true that $$\langle\langle A_1,B_1\rangle,\langle A_2,B_2\rangle\rangle=\langle\langle A_1,A_2\rangle,\langle B_1,B_2\rangle\rangle=\langle A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2\rangle,$$ where $\langle A,B\rangle$ is a subgroup generated by subgroups $A$ and $B$?

I used the definition $$\langle A,B\rangle=\langle A\cup B\rangle=\bigcap_{A\cup B\subseteq T} T .$$

For example,

$$\begin{align}
\langle\langle A_1,B_1\rangle,\langle A_2,B_2\rangle\rangle&=\left \langle\left(\bigcap_{A_1\cup B_1\subseteq T_1} T_1\right) \bigcup \left(\bigcap_{A_2\cup B_2\subseteq T_2} T_2\right)\right\rangle\\
&= \left\langle\bigcap_{A_1\cup B_1\subseteq T_1\\A_2\cup B_2\subseteq T_2} T_1\cup T_2\right\rangle\\
&=\left\langle\bigcap_{A_1\cup A_2\cup B_1\cup B_2\subseteq T} T\right\rangle\\
&=\langle A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2\rangle.
\end{align}$$

Analogous $\langle\langle A_1,A_2\rangle,\langle B_1,B_2\rangle\rangle=\langle A_1,A_2,B_1,B_2\rangle$.

Comment: I think so.  And $\langle A,B\rangle $ is called the join.

Comment: I don't see how $$\langle\langle A_1,B_1\rangle,\langle A_2,B_2\rangle\rangle=\left(\bigcap_{A_1\cup B_1\subseteq T_1} T_1\right) \bigcup \left(\bigcap_{A_2\cup B_2\subseteq T_2} T_2\right)$$

Comment: I made corrections

Comment: Now there are angle brackets that shouldn't be there.